# software updater will not detect 16.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

I am looking to upgrade to 16.04 but the updater will not detect it. Tried many mirrors, checked all the possible update icons. BTW, I am running 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

'While Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS has been released, automatic upgrades from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will not begin until "early next week" according to the Ubuntu Release Team.' https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/4tzgou/ubuntu_16041_lts_released_1404_users_see_upgrade/d5lp6s4